# Как правильно создать ajax запрос? \\ Лишние символы в ajax запросе

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Есть код, его суть заключается в отправке `ajax` запроса с содержимым поля ввода и типом действия(`banip`, `unbanip`) в некий `php` файл. Есть проблема: я получаю лишние символы в поле `IP`, ниже скину дамп переменной `$_POST`, в котором жирным текстом выделю лишние символы.

array(2) { ["action"]=> string(5) "block" ["ip"]=> string(14) "***ip=*** 192.168.1.1" }

Можно этот `ip=` как нибудь убрать? Может подскажите лучшую структуру для такого рода запросов?

Ниже сам код:

```js
function sendajax(type, url, data, out) {
  $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(result) {
      $('#' + out).html(result);
    }
  });
};

function blockip() {
  sendajax("POST", "includes/apanel/banip.php", {
    action: "block",
    ip: $("#banip").serialize()
  }, "not1");
};

function unblockip() {
  sendajax("POST", "includes/apanel/banip.php", {
    action: "unblock",
    ip: $("#banip").serialize()
  }, "not1");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ipban">
  <form onsubmit="return false;" id="banip">
    <input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" placeholder="123.1.1.0" style="width:146px; font-size: 11.5pt;">
    <button class="red-button" onclick="blockip();" style="width:90px;">BAN</button>
    <button class="green-button" id="unbanip" onclick="unblockip();" style="width:100px;">UNBAN</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `serialize` собирает в контейнере все инпуты, селекты и тд и формирует из них строку типа `name=val&name2=val2`

Ваш метод `sendajax` принимает `data` как объект того, что надо послать

В эту `data` вы устанавливаете след значение

```
{
    action: "unblock",
    ip: $("#banip").serialize()
}
```

То есть в параметр `ip` у вас записывается сериализованные данные типа, как я указал выше.

Вам надо в ip вставить значение, например так

```
{
    action: "unblock",
    ip: $("#ip").val()
}
```